# PHP - regex with two conditions

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking for a regex expression to use with php :

I have 4 strings like this in array :

```
$strA = 'John P. Beck';   // name and surname
$strB = '12012 BlaBla Xx';  // street
$strC = 'Houston TX 12345-6789';  // city + zip code
$strD = '(123) 456-7890';  // telephone number
```

By now i'm using a regex in a for loop but it always returns me both the first and the second string, and sometimes the first and the third string....

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++)
{
    if(preg_match("/[A-Z]/", $array[$i]))
    {
      echo $array[$i] . '<br>';
    }
    else echo 'no match<br>';
}
```

I need a regex with this conditions :
- at least 1 Uppercase in string AND absolutely NO digits... to return only $strA.....

Thank you very much

EDIT

sorry maybe I explained myself bad and without adding details...
This is the structure of the array (example):

```
[0] => <p>
[1] =>                41
[2] => <br />
[3] =>                John P. Beck
[4] => <br />
[5] =>                12012 BlaBla Xx
[6] => <br />
[7] =>                Houston TX 12345-6789
[8] => <br />
[9] =>                (123) 456-7890
[10] => <br />
[11] =>                42
[12] => <br />
[13] =>                Linda F. Green
[14] => <br />
[15] =>                1888 BlaBla Xx
[16] => <br />
[17] =>                Saint Louis, MO 12345-6789
[18] => <br />
[19] =>                (123) 456-7890
[20] => <br />
...
...
...
```

I need to store only the 4th string and the 14th string.. and so on ...

@nickb : with $array[0] it returns always a p tag.. i'm in a for loop...... :)

Comment: What is "joHn p. beck" ? (only the H is in upercase). Should pass or not ?

Comment: `echo $array[0];`. Problem solved.

Comment: It would help to know some sample inputs and desired outputs.  Your edit has <br> which makes me think it is output, but what was the input?

Comment: I am not sure why you need any sort of regex at all if your array is formed like that. Why not taking every item numbered N*10+3 or every item at +2 after a string that represents a valid  number?

Comment: you mean using a division and the mod operator (%) .... ? Yes I think it would be more mathematically correct but i needed a fast solution... I solved it with a regex by samsamX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0 or more chars (except digits), followed by one or more uppercase letter, followed by 0 or more chars (except digits) :

```
/[^0-9]*[A-Z]+[^0-9]*/
```

If you want your data beginning by the uppercase(s) letter(s) :

```
/^[A-Z]+[^0-9]*/
```

Comment: Show us 2 example isn't enought, you should specify exactly what you want. Are you searching for every 3 parts names ? Like `xxxxx X. xxxx` or `Xxxxx X. xxx` or even `Xxxx X. Xx` ?

Comment: the name can be Linda F. Green or even Linda Green or anything else but without digits..

Comment: don't matter if there is a space in the string .. my actually regex which is "/[A-Z]/" does return the name BUT ALSO the address "12012 BlaBla Xx" that i want to discard...

Comment: `/^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z]+( [A-Z]\.)? [A-Z]+[a-zA-Z]+$/` will accept `Linda F. Green` and `Linda Green`, but NOT `linda green`, `Linda F Green`, `Linda f. green`

Comment: The case insensitive version : `/^[a-zA-Z]+( [a-zA-Z]\.)? [a-zA-Z]+$/`

Comment: no luck.....   My site is : http://challenger6.sytes.net/test.php....  i will post the source of the script if needed

Comment: So my first attempt was enought for you. `/^[^0-9]*[A-Z][^0-9]*$/` will looks for string which doesn't have any digits, and at least an uppercase letter.

Comment: :) very good, thank you ... my first attempt did not work; your last regex seems perfect!! as you can check...  bye (and sorry but i don't speak english so well...)

Comment: Me neither ;) You're welcome, and please set this question as answered if you're done with.

Answer (score 0):

preg_match will match if **any part** of the string matches the regular expression.
If you want to test the whole string, use ^ and $ which represent the start and end of the string.

Comment: The "m" regex modifier to the regex will treat each \n as a new string.

Comment: @jordanm, no, `/m` only changes what `^` and `$` match.